# MODELO SARIMA. ERROR system is computationally singular

Tags: r, predicción

Estoy tratando de implementar un pronóstico a una serie de tiempo con el siguiente código, pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
fecha <- c
("01/01/2019","01/02/2019","01/03/2019","01/04/2019","01/05/2019","01/06/2019",
           "01/07/2019","01/08/2019","01/09/2019","01/10/2019","01/11/2019","01/12/2019")
fecha <-as.Date(fecha,format="%d/%m/%Y")
str(fecha)
valores <- c(1472561020,1948751475,1373499213,1442890441,1800262959,1390312460,1375627332,1626311641,1260676135,1446291783,1605898343,1535282371)

mod <- data.frame(fecha, valores)
serie <- ts(mod$valores)
Acf(valores)
plot.ts(serie)

ajuste <- sarima(serie,2,0,0)
```

> Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) :
>
> ```
> system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.83206e-17
> ```

Comment: Con que lenguaje estas trabajando y que IDE?

Comment: Buenas noches, con R, muchas gracias.